# "I mentioned that our office will be based here" vs "I mentioned that our office would be based here"

Tags: relative-clauses, subordinate-clauses, backshifting

"I mentioned that our office will be based here" vs "I mentioned that our office would be based here"

The questions is for something that has not been changed, and is just being repeated to someone with "I mentioned". So the office is not based, and there is emphasis on where the office will be based. Grammarly is saying we should use "would", but I found some web results with "will". "will" also sounds more natural to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do either, really. "Would" is a past tense of "will." Let's look at the timeline:

1. You made the mention ("Our office will be based here!")
2. Later, you retold that conversation ("I mentioned that our office ___ be based here.")
3. Finally, at some point in the future, the office opens and is "based here."

So, at stage #2, you could use "will" because it's still true—the opening is still in the future—or you can use "would" because you're retelling your past conversation. Personally, I would choose "would" as the most natural.

Note, [this page](https://writingexplained.org/will-vs-would-difference) says that you *can't* use would in this case; it's only for "something that was in the future at the time of the original action, but is no longer in the future now." So by their explanation, you could use it only after the office had opened. But I disagree with this, and think it's a misleading and unfounded requirement.

Now, all this has been assuming that the first conversation actually used "will." You could also have said, back then, "Our office would be based here." That's entirely different; now it's a "conditional," and means that the basing is uncertain, untrue, or depends on something ("Our office would be based here if we can't base it in Boston"). If this were the case, you would also use "would" when retelling the story.

One final note: If Grammarly alerts you to a problem, you should certainly look into it, but be aware that it's only an *artificial* intelligence, and language is complicated (especially English!). Sometimes it flags things as problems that are not.